# Does C still cast the product of two `int`s to be an `int` of the same size?

Tags: c, types, casting

I would appreciate if someone might point me to an authoritative reference (which I am having trouble finding).

In the olden days:

```
int32_t a, b;
int64_t c;
c = a*b;
```

this code did not do what I wanted in that the result of `a*b` continued to be a 32-bit word which was sign-extended into the 64-bit `c`.  I know I can cast either of `a` or `b` into `int64_t` before the multiplication, but this is in a deeply nested DSP algorithm and I don't want to waste a machine instruction that does the sign extend and I don't want the machine to do a 64x64 multiply.

What is the correct and efficient way to do this in a modern C compiler?

Comment: Your desires seem to be in conflict: you want `a*b` to be a 64-bit expression, yet you do not want the multiplication to be 64-bit. ???

Comment: @JaMiT: Multiplications do not have to be 32×32→32 or 64×64→64. Some processors have a 32×32→64 instruction. The challenge is in getting a C compiler to use it.

Comment: It's true that C doesn't have a built-in way to do a widening multiply.  If you write `c = (int64_t)a * b`, your compiler might realize that a widening multiply can be used (if your machine has one), or then again it might not.  For example, gcc on x86-32 does, and on x86-64 it does not. There might be non-portable intrinsics for your machine to access a widening multiply; otherwise you're down to inline asm if it's critical.

Comment: If the compiler is smart enough, adding the casts shouldn't emit sign extension instructions.

Comment: If you have a particular architecture / compiler in mind, someone may have suggestions for how to cajole the compiler to do what you want.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Well, I tested gcc on x86-64, and it actually doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/fcYqes.  Neither do clang nor icc.  But per uops.info it seems that on many machines 64x64=64 multiply is as fast or faster than 32x32=64, and 32x32=64 would leave the result in edx:eax, requiring some extra shifting to get into a single 64-bit register.  I guess the compiler thinks the cost of doing the sign extensions is less.

Comment: Incidentally, it's in a loop and you use `gcc -O3` to request vectorization, then the casted version generates `(v)pmuldq` which is a widening 32x32=64 vector multiply, as you might hope.  https://godbolt.org/z/677Ev3

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'm having trouble parsing the question. Parts of it seem to be asking about the C language, while other parts might be asking about micro-optimizations at the machine instruction level. (I had been viewing it at the C level.) It might be helpful if the question clarified if it was looking for the C language dictating a 32×32→64 multiplication or if it was looking for a compiler capable of producing a 32×32→64 multiplication (perhaps even if the compiler knows a faster way to accomplish the same result).

Comment: Well, I guess to the last sentence about the "correct and efficient" way: there's really only one correct way to do it, namely cast one or both operands, so "efficient" is moot.  However modern compilers will indeed generate efficient code for this.

Comment: *// ...might be helpful if the question clarified if it was looking for the C language dictating a 32×32→64 multiplication or if it was looking for a compiler capable of producing a 32×32→64 multiplication //*

uhm, @JaMiT i am looking for the most efficient way to implement `c = (int64_t)a * (int64_t)b;` without causing sign extension or a 64×64→64 multiplication.  i want it to do only a 32×32→64  mult instruction.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Your comment does not mention a compiler, which might be progress. You might want to drop *"in a modern C compiler"* from your question's *"What is the correct and efficient way to do this in a modern C compiler?"* If you want that level of control over the machine code, you should consider assembly. An optimizing C compiler's goal is the most efficient implementation, not the most efficient implementation that arbitrarily avoids certain operations. *(While the most efficient implementation might not use those operations, a good compiler will not a priori exclude them.)*

Comment: @EricPostpischil: *"Some processors have a 32×32→64 instruction."* -- this suggests that some do not. So any trick that forces a 32×32→64 instruction to be produced is inherently not portable?

Comment: @JaMiT: It depends what sort of “force” is used. GCC, for example, has builtins for a number of things that correspond to various processor features, such as a builtin for find-first-bit-set. When the builtin is used, the compiler will use the corresponding instruction (or something it “believes” to be equally good) if it exists in the target architecture but will use other instructions if it does not. So that sort of “force” will not break a program when compiled for other architectures. However, using inline assembly to specify the instruction will work only if the instruction exists.

Comment: // If you want that level of control over the machine code, you should consider assembly. An optimizing C compiler's goal is the most efficient implementation, not the most efficient implementation that arbitrarily avoids certain operations.// @JaMiT the original thing is that while it's sensible that the addition or subtraction of two `int32_t` variables should be an `int32_t`. but the immediate result of the multiplication or two `int32_t` integers should be an `int64_t` which can then be optionally cast back to an `int32_t`. that's how the language should be defined, but it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.5 discusses multiplicative operators, and its paragraph 3 says “The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.”

6.3.1.8 specifies the usual arithmetic conversions. Its second sentence says “The purpose is to determine a *common real type* for the operands **and** result” (italic in the original, bold added). This is followed by rules that specify the resulting type. For `int32_t` operands that are not lower rank than `int` (effectively meaning they are not narrower than `int`), this type is `int32_t`. Thus `a*b` yields an `int32_t` result regardless of what it is being assigned to.

If you write `c = (int64_t) a * b`, a compiler might recognize that the cast has no effect on the values of `a` or `b` but that the result will be 64 bits, and so a compiler might use a 32×32→64 multiplication instruction if the target architecture has one (or multiple instructions to the same effect). However, this is not required by the C standard and would depend on the compiler.

Comment: // so a compiler might use a 32×32→64 multiplication instruction if the target architecture has one (or multiple instructions to the same effect). However, this is not required by the C standard and would depend on the compiler.//

yeah, that's the problem.  i just wish i could write clean and portable generic C code to do DSP without a pragma or something to make the compiler do exactly what i want it to.